# How to estimate the probability of max balanced biclique in a random bipartite graph?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

Give a random bipartite graph $G=(V,U,E)$ and $|V|=|U|=n$, the edge between vertex pair $<v,u>$ ($v\in V$,$u\in U$) exists with probability $p\in [0,1]$. A balanced bipartite complete graph is a biclique $G(X,Y,E)$ that $|X|=|Y|$ and $E=X\times Y$ . So, does you have an idea about how to estimate the distribution of maximum size of balanced biclique?

Comment: Since given a biclique of large size further cliques of the same or larger size are unlikely, a first estimate would be that the probability for a balanced biclique of size $k$ to exist is roughly the expected value of the number of balanced bicliques of size $k$ (which is $\binom nk^2p^{k^2}$) and the probability for $k$ to be the maximal size is roughly the same.